# api for adding values into multi-value property into FileNet P8 in Java

Tags: java, arrays, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have a property tag

```
<property id="accountNumbers">0000111|00000222|000033</property>
```

I am able to read and separate using pipe but I am looking for the method to upload these values into fileNet where accountNumbers field is set to multi-value property. My guess is

```
doc.getProperties().putValue( accountNumbers, String.valueOf( accountNumbersSplit) );
```

I have created a list of those values by separating with the name accountNumbersSplit and trying to upload this list into accountNumbers field.

**edit**

this is how I have separated and stored in a List

```
String [] accountNumbersSplit = groupNumberValue.split( "\\|" ); 
List <String> accountList = Arrays.asList( accountNumbersSplit);
```

this is how I am trying to upload

```
doc.getProperties().putValue( accountNumbers, String.valueOf( accountNumbersSplit) );
```

Comment: You may get more help if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: this is how i have separated and stored in a List                                             
               String [] accountNumbersSplit = groupNumberValue.split( "\\|" );
                      List <String> accountList = Arrays.asList( groupNumberSplit );                                               this is how i am trying to upload                                                                   doc.getProperties().putValue( accountNumbers, String.valueOf( accountNumbersSplit) );

Answer (score 0):

If your property is a multi-value, than it's property datatype should be PropertyStringListImpl, so the value you want to set it to, has to be of datatype StringList -> Try using the StringList datatype when putting the value... also the first argument in putValue() is the name of the property (String), so is accountNumbers a String containing the correct propertyname?

```
StringList accountNumbersSplit;
doc.getProperties().putValue(propertyName, accountNumbersSplit);
```